# MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionBuilder.setArgListKind()

Tags: intellij-idea, mocking, spock, stubbing

I couldnt find this problem described anywhere, so I'm posting for anyone else who spots this.

I found that running any example of spock stubbing using the '>>' or '>>>' is failing with the same exception. 
`MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionBuilder.setArgListKind() is applicable for argument types: (Boolean, Boolean) values: [true, false]`

for example, from [Javitar: Spock Testing – Spock tutorial](http://thejavatar.com/testing-with-spock/)

```
def "should return Role.USER when asked for role"() {
        given:
        List list = Stub()
        list.size() >> 3
        expect:
        // let's see if this works
        list.size() == 3
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running: spockVersion=1.3-groovy-2.5

Intellij runs Spock tests using a Junit template. I found the solution here:
[Combining Spock 1.2 and Junit 5 tests](https://thoughts.tostring.blog/spock-jupiter/)
the solution was to add the following to my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.1"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.6.1"
}

test { // only needed if doing 'gradle test' 
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am running this code in Intellij/Idea 2019.3, using

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.2.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-04 08:49:31 UTC
Revision:     7d0bf6dcb46c143bcc3b7a0fa40a8e5ca28e5856

Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_152 (Azul Systems, Inc. 25.152-b16)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-52-generic amd64
Linux Mint 19 Tara
```